# Do not show pull window TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

I do need to pull a lot, and now I need to click Git Pull, click OK and then it pulls. Is there an option to skip this window? I never change the pull options so it has no use for me.

I've searched the settings but I can't find it anywhere..

Using TortoiseGit 1.8.15.0

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using **Git Synchronization dialog**.

Right click on you repo and click context menu item **Git Sync...**.

Show you:

[image]

Then, keep this dialog opened.

If that button does not present **Pull** for you, using the drop menu to select Pull.

[image]